# SearchView stops working when switch tab

Tags: android, search, tabs, searchview

I have 3 fragments in a TabLayout as seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBoUy.jpg

Whenever I start the application, it opens the explorer tab, and I can switch to the search tab and the searchview works perfectly. If I switch to explorer and back to search, it still works.

My SearchView does not use a searchable activity, but instead searches with an onQueryTextChange listener. Below the SearchView is a LinearLayout with 30 TextViews whose text are changed by searching.

However, if I switch to the quiz tab and back to search, the SearchView text remains, but the TextViews are reset to their default values of "gone", like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVzzO.jpg. Trying to search now using the SearchView does not work.

It seems that switching to the quiz tab deflates my search layout, and when I switch back, it inflates the search layout but does not instantiate the SearchView properly. When I try to search again, OnQueryTextChange is not called. I cannot figure out why it does this.

The problem started when I added a SearchView to QuizLayout.xml, and added code for a second SearchView to the onCreateOptionsMenu in MainActivity for the quiz tab. However even after commenting it out and making sure all IDs were correct, the problem still happens.

Below is my code, with some (hopefully) irrelevant code omitted.

My SearchFragment:

```
package com.example.ryans45attcdie.chess;

public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_fragment, container, false);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        searchLayout = 
        (LinearLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.searchLayoutS);
    }
}
```

My QuizFragment: (empty for debugging)

```
public class QuizFragment extends Fragment {}
```

My MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView sname1;//(etc.)

ArrayList<TextView> masterNameListS;

List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<>();
ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //set up fragments in tabs

    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, QuizFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, 
    ExplorerFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, 
    SearchFragment.class.getName()));

    PagerAdaptor adaptor = new PagerAdaptor(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
    fragments);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    pager.setAdapter(adaptor);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText("QUIZ");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText("EXPLORE");
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setText("SEARCH");

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), 
    android.R.layout.list_content, listItems);

    pager.setCurrentItem(1);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    sname1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sname1); //(etc.)

    final ArrayList<TextView> masterNameListS = new ArrayList<>();

    masterNameListS.add(sname1); //(etc.)

    // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManagerS = (SearchManager) 
    getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    SearchView searchViewS = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchViewS);

    // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
    ComponentName cnS = new ComponentName(this, SearchableActivity.class);
    searchViewS.setSearchableInfo(searchManagerS.getSearchableInfo(cnS));
    searchViewS.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; 
    expand it by default
    searchViewS.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

            //parse search string and set TextView texts here   

            return true;

        }

    });
    return true;
    }

    @Override
public booleafn onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And PagerAdapter:

```
    package com.example.ryans45attcdie.chess;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import java.util.List;

public class PagerAdaptor extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PagerAdaptor(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);

        this.fragments = fragments;
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    return fragments.get(i);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return fragments.size();
    }
}
```

My QuizLayout.xml is empty.
My SearchLayout.xml creates all the TextViews with no text and Visibility.GONE.

Thanks very much for the help guys,

Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it :)

The issue was that ViewPager keeps, by default, only one off-screen tab in memory. Because my explorer tab was opened first, this was stored in memory. When I switched from search to quiz, my ViewPager decided to delete the search tab, and keep the explorer tab.

To fix this, put `your_View_Pager_here.setOffscreenPageLimit(number_to_store);` in your MainActivity onCreate method.